# C++ SDL 2.0 - Importing multiple textures using a loop

Tags: c++

I don't know whether or not this is possible but I have used this technique in different languages but am struggling to use it in C++. I have 10 images that I am trying to load into an array using a loop as so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Sprite[i] = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "Graphics/Player" + i + ".png");
}
```

This however does not seem to work in C++ so I was wondering what I am doing wrong, or what can I do to get the same result without having to load each image individually like so:

```
Sprite[0] = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "Graphics/Player0.png");
```

My error is: "Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Thanks for any help =)

Comment: Well, for one thing you got the for loop the wrong way round. It's for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++). Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed the loop, ill edit it out, but it doesn't seem to like it when I combine the i into the string. It just creates an error.

Comment: please more details on what is failing, eg the compiler error or so. i suppose the `+` operator on `string` and the `int` is the problem here, you would need to use something like `std::to_string`

Comment: The error is as you said within this part of the code: "Graphics/Player" + i + ".png");. I have tried creating a string variable above it and playing that in its place instead, I just tried what you said about converting to a string as well but it still doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: My error is: "Expression must have integral or unscoped enum type"

Answer (score 0):

#### You cannot do this:

`"This is my number: " + (int)4 + "!";`

This is illegal. It will give you an error for trying to operator+ a const char* and a const char[SOME_INT_GOES_HERE] or another error for trying to use operator+ to add an int onto a string. Things just don't work that way.

**You'd either have to use C (i.e. snprintf()) or a string stream.** Here's my test code for isolating your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
        int a = 1;
        std::string str = "blah";
        std::string end =  "!";

        //std::string hello = str + a + end;// GIVES AN ERROR for operator+
        std::string hello = "blah" + a + "!";
      
        //const char* c_str = "blah" + a + "end";
        //std::cout << c_str << std::endl;
        std::cout << hello << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

**Here's an alternative solution using string streams.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::string str;
    std::stringstream ss;
    
    while (i < 10)
    {
        //Send text to string stream.
        ss << "text" << i;
        
        //Set string to the text inside string stream
        str = ss.str();
        
        //Print out the string
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        
        //ss.clear() doesn't work. Calling a constructor
        //for std::string() and setting ss.str(std::string())
        //will set the string stream to an empty string.
        ss.str(std::string());
        
        //Remember to increment the variable inside of while{}
        ++i;
    }
}
```

**Alternatively, you can also use std::to_string() if you're using C++11 (which just requires -std=c++11) but std::to_string() is broken on some sets of compilers (i.e. regular MinGW).** Either switch to another flavor where it works (i.e. MinGW-w64) or just write your own to_string() function using string streams behind the scenes.

snprintf() may be the fastest way of doing such a thing, but for safer C++ and better style, it is recommended you use a non-C way of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I shall look into it =)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solwed it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   string line;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       line = "Graphics/Player" + inttostr(i) + ".png"; //I wrote inttostr function because built in inttostr functions messed up my program (see below)
       char charger[line.length()]; //creating char array
       for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(line); i++) {
           charger[i] = line[i]; // copying string to char arry
       }
       Sprite[i] = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, charger);
    }   
}

string inttostr(int integer) { //I know it isn't the best way to convert integer to string, but it works
    string charakter;
    int swap;
    bool negativ = false;

    if (integer < 0) {
        integer = -integer;
        negativ = true;
    }
    if (integer == 0) {
        charakter = "0";
    }
    while (integer >= 1) {
        swap = integer % 10;
        integer = integer / 10;
        charakter = char(swap + 48) + charakter;
    }
    if (negativ) {
        charakter = "-" + charakter;
    }
    return charakter;
}
```